# div overlapping with ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, google-visualization

On ajax call, one div that is declared in my html using bootstrap disappears.

The first time the chart is loaded, the dropdown input field is disappears.

Here is my html using bootstrap code. Note, some parent div is eliminated here for better readability.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
            <h2>Certificates Report using Google Chart</h2>
            <div id="certificate-container">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label for="days_cert">Interval:</label>
                        <select name="days" id="days_cert" class="form-control table-filter">
                            <option value="1"  >1 day ago</option>
                            <option value="7">7 days ago</option>
                            <option value="30">1 month ago</option>
                            <option value="90">3 month ago</option>
                            <option value="365" selected>1 year ago</option>
                            <option value="730">2 year ago</option>
                        </select>
                        <!-- /input-group -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="chart-container">
                    <div id="chart_div"></div>
                    <div id="piechart" style="width: 500px; height: 300px;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Here is my Script file.

```
var real_data;
var real_data_payment;
var real_data_enrollment;
var requestInput;
var dataCert;
var requestInputPay;
var dataPay;
var requestInputEnroll;
var dataEnroll;

        days_cert.addEventListener('change', function() {
               requestInput = new RequestInput($("#days_cert").val());
               dataCert = JSON.stringify(requestInput);
               updateChartDataCertificate();
               loadCharts();
        });
    
        requestInput = new RequestInput($("#days_cert").val());
        dataCert = JSON.stringify(requestInput);
        function updateChartDataCertificate() {
            $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/api/charts/certificates/count',
                    data: dataCert,
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(response) {
                      console.log(dataCert);
                      //console.log(response);
                      // Update the real_data variables with the new data
                      real_data = response;
                      console.log(real_data);
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                      var requestInput = new RequestInput($("#days_cert").val());
                      console.log(JSON.stringify(requestInput));
                      // console.error(error);
                    }
                  });
        }
        
        $(document).ready(function() {
            updateChartDataCertificate();
            loadCharts();
    
        });
        function loadCharts() {
            google.charts.load('current', {
                    packages : [ 'corechart', 'bar' ]
                });
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawColumnChart);
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawPieChart);
            
        }
        function RequestInput(days) {
                this.days = days;
        }
        function drawColumnChart() {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Type');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Count');
            console.log(real_data);
            Object.keys(real_data).forEach(function(key) {
                data.addRow([ key, real_data[key] ]);
            });
            var options = {
                title : 'Certificate Stats',
                chartArea: {
                        bottom: 40
                    },
                hAxis : {
                    title : 'Type',
                    textStyle: {
                        fontSize: 8,
                        fontStyle: "Arial",
                        marginTop: '25'
                    }
                },
                vAxis : {
                    title : 'Count'
                }
            };
            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document
                    .getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
       function drawPieChart() {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Type');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Count');
            Object.keys(real_data).forEach(function(key) {
                data.addRow([ key, real_data[key] ]);
            });
            var options = {
                title : 'Certificate Stats',
                is3D: true,
                pieSliceTextStyle: {
                    fontSize: 8
                }
            };
            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document
                    .getElementById('piechart'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
```

Here are some screenshots of before and after clicking the dropdown:

**Before**

[image: before clicking the dropdown or no option is selected]

**After**

[image: after clicking the dropdown or one option is selected]

Comment: Can you still see your dropdown in the DOM on inspection?

Comment: I think so. But it is overridden maybe.
here is the screenshot.
https://ibb.co/CQBfvZM

Comment: Probably just put your form-group and your chart-container in two new divs with the `row` class and should fix it.